# Executar recursos do windows com Java

Tags: java

Estou desenvolvendo um emissor NFe e tem uma opção no windows que permite vc selecionar qual certificado usar. Gostaria de saber se alguém sabe como chamar esse recurso do windows usando Java.

Answer (score 2):

Tenta deste modo:

```
Imports

import java.security.KeyStore;  
import java.security.KeyStoreException;  
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;  
import java.security.NoSuchProviderException;  
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
```

Função

```
KeyStore instance = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY", "SunMSCAPI");  

instance.load(null, null);  

Enumeration<String> dados = instance.aliases();  

List<String> certificados = new ArrayList<String>();  
while(dados.hasMoreElements())  
{  
    certificados.add(dados.nextElement());  
}  

for (String cert : certificados)  
{  
    System.out.println(cert);  
}
```

Exemplo:

[image: Demonstracao saida]

Comment: @MrcoGiovani. Ajudou sim. Na verdade, esqueci de detalhar mais o que preciso. O que precisaria mesmo era aquela Janelinha gráfica que o próprio windows tem, pq o certificado que quero é o A3.

Comment: Oi, nunca utilizei para listar o A3, tenta dar uma olhada [neste](http://devbrasil.net/group/nfce-em-java/page/como-o-java-trabalha-com-certificados-digitais) tutorial